# How to separate view and data in Ajax response from codeigniter controller

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am sending data and view from CodeIgniter controller to Ajax using code

```
$this->load->model('query_mainmodel');
$data['result'] = $this->query_mainmodel->getcategories();  
print $this->load->view('add_content',$data,true);
```

and in Ajax I have

```
$.ajax({
     url: url,
     type: 'POST',
     dataType: "text",
     success: function (response) {
       tabID.html(response); //now this time response contains html only
     }
});
```

I got HTML in response,**How can I get data from ajax?**

Comment: It looks like you're doing it. What is the value of data?

Comment: now value of data in Ajax response is html,I edited code in ajax (data to response )for avoid confusion

Comment: What more or less are you expecting or hoping for?

Comment: I am expecting database query result including view

Comment: So you want two things, right?

Comment: yes,both view and data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say you can get html, but now you want data. So in your controller, you can pass a view and data back as json:

```
$data['result'] = $this->query_mainmodel->getcategories();

echo json_encode( array(
    'view_html' => $this->load->view('add_content',$data,true),
    'data'      => $data['result']
));
```

Then in your JS:

```
$.ajax({
     url: url,
     type: 'POST',
     dataType: "json", // <- make sure to change this
     success: function (response) {
       // view HTML available like this
       console.log( response.view_html );

       // data available like this
       console.log( response.data );
     }
});
```

Comment: By the way, you can do this for many things. Try it with 5 or 10 things. It is very powerful.